# Match exact words single or multiple words using highlight plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to exactly match the Arabic keywords with Arabic text. I am using Highlight plugin which works fine for English version but breaks in arabic.

If we use `partial` option in script then it will match the partial  string but i want to use `exact` feature which breaks the script as it may not be supported by the plugin. I tried different thing but nothing seems to work so far with Arabic text matching and highlighting

Below is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tg8vtpqk/2/

i tried `regex = '(\\b' + regex + '\\b)(?=\\s|$)';` for exact match but it breaks the string while same works in C#.

I have been looking for any plugin which can highlight exact words of Arabic text.

Answer (score 0):

encode the special characters first.
var myArabicString = myArabicString.replace(/([^\w\d\s])/g,'\' + '$1');
var myRegex = RegExp(myArabicString);